# How to pretty print record types?

Tags: haskell

Given a record like `Example {a = "a", b = "b", c = "c"}` how can I pretty print **any** record type like this to make it easier to read (more human friendly)?

Somthing like:

```
Example {
  a = "a"
, b = "b"
, c = "c"
}
```

would be ideal.

I've tried [pPrint](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pretty-show-1.6.13/docs/Text-Show-Pretty.html#v:pPrint) from the `pretty-show` package but this doesn't seem to output any different to `show`.

Comment: `show` is defined by the `Prelude`. If you want to pretty-print data, you should probably use one of the functions from that other package.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be achieved with: [`pretty-simple`](https://github.com/cdepillabout/pretty-simple):

```
ghci> import Text.Pretty.Simple (pPrint)
ghci> data Example = Example { a, b, c :: String } deriving Show
ghci> pPrint Example {a = "a", b = "b", c = "c"}
Example 
    { a = "a"
    , b = "b"
    , c = "c"
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

As @SwiftsNamesake points out try something like Text.Show.Pretty

```
import Text.Show.Pretty 

data Example = Example
    { a :: String
    , b :: String
    , c :: String
    } deriving (Show) 

main = print $ ppShow Example {a = "a", b = "b", c = "c"}
```

Comment: Output: `Example { a = "a" , b = "b" , c = "c" }`.  I'd like the parameters to be on their own line.

Comment: It seems to depend on the line length. Try setting `a` to some longer phrase.